# Change value of Two-Dimensional Array in Processing 3

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I'm making a singleplayer Battleship game in Processing 3. 
To generate the playing field, I create a two-dimensional array that holds a boolean value for whether the grid cell has been clicked. To generate this array, I use to following function:

```java
boolean[][] clicked = {};

void initArray(int gridSize) {
    boolean[] row = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) row = (boolean[]) append(row, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) clicked = (boolean[][]) append(clicked, row);
}
```

The issue I'm having is that whenever I try to change one cell's value to true, all the values in that row become true as well. This is the code I use to change and print the array:

```java
void setup() {
    initArray(3);
    clicked[2][1] = true;
    println(clicked[0]);
    println(clicked[1]);
    println(clicked[2]);
}
```

I only want to change the second value of the third row, but instead it changes the second value of every row. Here is the output:

```
[0] false
[1] true
[2] false
[0] false
[1] true
[2] false
[0] false
[1] true
[2] false
```

I'm not allowed to use OOP for this assignment.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create only one `row` object and you append this object to each row. At the end each row refers to the same `row` object. So it seems to be that changing the element of one row affects the other rows too.

Create a sparte `row` object for each row of the grid, to solve your issue:

```java
boolean[][] clicked = {};

void initArray(int gridSize) {

    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        boolean[] row = {}; // <--- new object for each row
        for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++)
            row = (boolean[]) append(row, false);
        clicked = (boolean[][]) append(clicked, row);
    }
}
```